# css padding issue on chrome

Tags: html, css, padding

I have designed a navigation list using css. Below is my code

```css
ul#mainnavigation li a {
    font: 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    font-weight:600;
    color:#686868;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 19.7px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.1s linear, background 0.1s linear, border-left-color 0.1s linear, border-bottom-color 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition:color 0.1s linear, background 0.1s linear, border-left-color 0.1s linear, border-bottom-color 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition:color 0.1s linear, background 0.1s linear, border-left-color 0.1s linear, border-bottom-color 0.1s linear;
    transition:color 0.1s linear, background 0.1s linear, border-left-color 0.1s linear, border-bottom-color 0.1s linear;
    z-index:100;
}
```

The problem that I'm having is in firefox it works perfectly but in chrome the last navigation element is gone below.

In firefox `padding:0 25.7px;` gives the correct results

In chrome `padding: 0 26.5px;` gives the correct results

How can I make sure that the padding works on both the browsers correctly?

Note: I have defined the doctype as `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: are you using a reset stylesheet..?

Comment: My guess would be that the two browsers are calculating your decimal pixel width differently.  For that matter, when using pixels, you're dealing with the most finite unit you can use on a screen, so why do you even need a decimal on it?  Just use 25 or 26 and then it should be universal no matter what.

Comment: Use `display: block; float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @danp im not using a reset stylesheet.

Comment: @Michael even 25 works in firefox but 26 doesnt. even i used values without decimal values still the problem exist.

Comment: @MichaelMalinovskij doesnt weems to work.

Comment: I would avoid fractional pixels entirely as different browsers treat them differently. Some round up, some down,  and some truncate. See http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

As you're finding, different browsers often render slightly different pixel sizes for the same elements - this is often because of font sizes and how the browser scales fonts, but can be for a variety of reasons.

My suggestions would be:

1) If the navigation menu MUST be 50px high, scale the elements inside to leave a little bit of extra room for browser causing problems, or:

2) You can also remove the hardcoded 50px height on the menu, and let it automatically scale to fit its elements. If anything inside the menu is floated, removing the "height" attribute on the menu container and adding an "overflow:hidden;" attribute to your CSS should cause the menu to expand to the height of everything inside it.